# use of "Perhaps with "would have"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct out of the following?

1. Perhaps he has done it.
2. Perhaps he would have done it.

Can we use 'perhaps' with 'would have' for a thing that we speculate or doubt was done by someone? Or does the word 'perhaps' fulfill the need of speculation thus we simply use present perfect tense is situation like this?

Comment: *perhaps* indicates the speaker's uncertainty, while *would have* refers to uncertainty regarding his (he) actions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because they refer to different things within the sentence.

**Perhaps** refers to the narrator's inquiring of 'his' actions.

**Would have** refers to a conditional action, if a different scenario had played out.